# UpdatePanel Jquery Modal Dialog update issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have Jquery Dialog in which there are  State and Districts dropdown lists inside an Update panel as follows

```
<tr>
<td class="newLabel"><span >State </span></td><td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="Dd_state" class="keyitem" runat="server" style="width:200px;"> 
    </asp:DropDownList></td> </tr>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnd_district" runat="server" onload="updPnd_district_Load">
    <Triggers> 
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID ="Dd_state" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <tr><td class="newLabel"><span >District </span></td><td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_district" runat="server" style="width:200px;" class="keyitem"> </asp:DropDownList></td> </tr>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am opening this dialog on click event of a button which will call the following function

```
function showNewDialog() {
   $('#<%=empnew.ClientID%>').dialog({ autoOpen: true ,modal: true, height: 550, width: 850 });
   $('#<%=empnew.ClientID%>').parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

}
```

My problem is after the first post back from the state drop down , update panel is not working and after the postback the content of the div is displayed in the page (out side of the dialog)

Whats wrong in my code

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
function showNewDialog() {
  var dlg = $('#<%=empnew.ClientID%>').dialog({ autoOpen: true ,modal: true, height: 550, width: 850 });
   dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

}
```

Comment: When and how do you call that function? Do you need to re-open it after postback?

Comment: Try to place this bit of code in your `$(document).ready()` block     `<% if (Page.IsPostback) { %>
            $('#<%=empnew.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
        <% } %>`

Comment: i am getting error in this line  

    <% if (Page.IsPostback) { %> 
             $('#<%=empnew.ClientID%>').trigger('click'); 
    <% } %> 
Error at design time : "Expression expected"

Comment: Change single quotes to double

Comment: now its working but problem is still there ... the dialog will open but once i select a state from drop down , then the content in the dialog will appended to the page  and the dialog stop to respond

Comment: This is because you are telling to do that. Change that line `dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));` to `dlg.dialog("open");`

Comment: yes ... i did it but no luck!!

funny thing is.. the dropdown (state and district)  in the appended div works as expected .. but not in the dialog

Comment: i moved it a new page instead of JQuery dialog. Thanks Morpheus